# Beamer: make a movie play only up to certain time

Tags: beamer, media9, video

Is it possible to embed a video in Beamer and make it `AutoPlay` but say just up to the first 10 seconds?

I have an `mp4` movie that I am embedding by `media9` package, but reading the DOCs of this latter I could not find any reference to this possibility.

Currently:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{
     \usetheme{Madrid}
     \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
} 

\uspackage{media9}
\addmediapath{{../Figures/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Background}
    \includemedia[width=0.4\linewidth,
                height=0.3\linewidth,
                activate=pageopen,
                addresource=../Figures/Saturated_Reconstruction.mp4,
                flashvars={source=../Figure/Saturated_Reconstruction.mp4}]{}{VPlayer.swf}
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Trivially, you could crop the original file with an editor or a command line tool, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/a/821284/540457 for Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, true. But this is what I would like to avoid. I found an option in `\movie` from package `multimedia` inside `beamer` such as `start` and `duration`. This requires to convert my movie to `AVI` a priori (not a big deal by `ffmpeg`)... the point is that for some reasons, these options do not work...